# How do I link a headervaluerouter to input channel?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, integration

I have created a headervaluerouter bean

```
@Bean
public HeaderValueRouter router (){
    HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter("received");
    router.setChannelMapping("response","replyCh");
    router.setChannelMapping("request","requestCh");
    //router.setManagedName();
    return router;
}
```

But router has no way to set the input channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router is `MessageHandler` implementation. And it's responsibility is just to handle message. The input channel is a part of consumer endpoint logic. For that purpose you can mark this router bean with the `@ServiceActivator` or just `@Router`. You can find more info in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips